# Morphia Gives "Possible Heterogeneous Collection" Warning For Non-Collection Field

Tags: morphia

*This is a follow-up question to [Manual Conversion of 3rd Party Class With Morphia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295650/manual-conversion-of-3rd-party-class-with-morphia)*

I've an `@Entity` class which has a field of type **`javax.activation.MimeType`**. When I run my application I see a warning message in the output window, telling

> WARNING: The multi-valued field
>   'javax.activation.MimeTypeParameterList.parameters' is a possible
>   heterogeneous collection. It cannot be verified. Please declare a
>   valid type to get rid of this warning. class java.lang.Object

I've already written and registered a type converter class for the type "MimeType", which effectively just ignores its 'parameters' field. But the warning keeps coming.I debugged it and saw that the warning was issued when `datastore.ensureIndexes();` is called.

I tried writing a type converter for "MimeTypeParameterList" type but it didn't supress the warning. I can't just go and put a `@Transient` annotation over the field declaration because it's third party code (Java SE core!), not mine.

Is there an "elegant" way to eliminate this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pushed a change to morphia's github repo that suppresses that logging for you.  It'll be in 0.108 or you can build it locally if you want to try it out.